# How to bring inner boxes at same level

Tags: html, css

I want the inner two divs to be positioned as:
 _________   _________
|         | |         |
|         | |         |
|         | |         |
|_________| |         |
            |         |
            |_________|

Now what happens is when they both are empty or the data in them is simple with only text then it looks like this only. But when i use 
 and if i make more divs inside them with some margin then the shorter in height box starts going down. But i want the the first box to be stagnant at its position.

P.s. i have drawn the patter but if in case it gets distorted after i post this question then please run the code.

```html
<html>
<head><title>abc</title>
<style>
 #biggerbox{
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
 #first{
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
 #second{
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="biggerbox">
  <div id="first">
   This is first box
  </div>
  <div id="second">
   This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i didnt get anything. can you please explain more and if you want to show us some design then provide image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head><title>abc</title>
<style>
    #biggerbox{
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    #first, #second{
        width: 500px;
        height: 600px;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="biggerbox">
        <div id="first">
            This is first box
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>This is second box
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update css

**Css**

```
 #biggerbox{
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid;
    display: inline-block;

    }
    #first{
        width: 500px;
        height: 600px;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid;

    }
    #second{
        width: 500px;
        height: 800px;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid;

    }
  .center
  {

    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: auto;

  }
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/k6bbo8up/)

Comment: But i want them to be center aligned as well when the browser window is resized

Comment: thnx for your help but again the whole div with the class center is left aligned...vertical-align: top serves the purpose

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` in css of the each div.